# couldn't able to open existing projects in android adt(eclipse)

Tags: java, android, eclipse, adt

I've a problem in eclipse, i'm getting the following error and i couldn't able to open any existing projects and not able create any new project as well. I've tried restarting eclipse but it's not working.

[image]

Comment: Do you updated your ADT??

Comment: no, i didn't updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally it worked after I've uninstalled JDK and installed it again. Thank you all